Jupyter server zmq connection using php client
I am trying to connect to communicate to jupyter server using zmq messages sent by my PHP script. But the connection between zmq server and my PHP script is not being established.
I tried assigning ports in jupyter notebook config which is located at
~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py 
c.NotebookApp.ip = '127.0.0.1'
c.NotebookApp.port = 9992
c.Session.key = b'00f2400c-bea977d0c80f0'
c.ConnectionFileMixin.shell_port = 37971
c.ConnectionFileMixin.iopub_port = 36612
c.ConnectionFileMixin.control_port = 51091
c.ConnectionFileMixin.hb_port = 55613
c.NotebookApp.token = '12345'
c.ConnectionFileMixin.ip = '0.0.0.0'
c.KernelManager.autorestart = True

and the PHP script trying to connect is
<?php

// Load the ZMQ extension
$context = new ZMQContext();

// Create a new socket of type Request (REQ)
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_REQ);

// Connect to the server
$socket->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:55613");

for ($request = 0; $request < 10; $request++)
{
    echo "Sending request $request...\n";

    // Command to send.
    $socket->send("Heartbeat");

    // Get the reply.
    $reply = $socket->recv();

    echo "Received reply $request: [$reply]\n";
}

when I connect to the notebook after starting it, no response is coming back from server.
The output from php script is just - "Sending request 0...\n"; as socket sent message by does not receive any reply from server and I think it keeps waiting for response.

What is the output when you run that script? Please [edit] it into the question.
